# How to rename file on upload to server using RecordID from Filemaker Server

Tags: php, html, database, file-upload, filemaker

Hi Guys I am having an issue with a Filemaker database website that I have. I have a form that allows users to enter some details and submit them to a filemaker database (At this point a record id is created). On the next page the users details are shown and the RecordID is echoed on the page, the following page allows the user to upload a file to the server, this all works but I want to be able to rename the file on upload to the same as the record id so that we can link file uploads to records in the database.

So currently I have three pages, an addRecord page which allows the user to enter their details, a confirmation page which displays the users details and has a link to the upload page, and finally an upload page which allows the user to upload an image. All of the code is working currently but I can’t seem to work out how to get the image uploaded with the name of the RecordID that was previously created.

Here is the form that I have to submit the user data:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<?php
    require_once 'fmview.php';
    require_once 'FileMaker.php';
    require_once 'error.php';

    $cgi = new CGI();
    $cgi->storeFile();

    $databaseName = ‘database’;
    $layoutName = ‘layout’;

    $userName = ‘*********’;
    $passWord = ‘*********’;

    $fm = & new FileMaker();
    $fm->setProperty('database', $databaseName);
    $fm->setProperty('username', $userName);
    $fm->setProperty('password', $passWord);

    ExitOnError($fm);
    $layout = $fm->getLayout($layoutName);
    ExitOnError($layout);

    // formats for dates and times
    $displayDateFormat = '%d/%m/%Y';
    $displayTimeFormat = '%H:%M:%S';
    $displayDateTimeFormat = '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S';
    $submitDateOrder = 'mdy';

    class EmptyRecord {
        function getRelatedSet($relationName) {
            return array(new EmptyRecord());
        }

        function getField($field, $repetition = 0) {
        }

        function getRecordId() {
        }
    }

    $record = new EmptyRecord();
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>
            Add Record
        </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="agentis.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
                Database
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <?php include_once 'navigation.php'; ?>
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="contentbg">
                <tr>
                    <td class="contentmidrecords">
                        <div id="contenttitlebg">
                            <h1>
                                Add Record
                            </h1>
                        </div>
                        </table>
                        <div class="scrolladd">
                            <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" class="recwidth">
                                <tr>
                                    <td valign="top">
                                        <form method="post" action="confirmation.php">
                                            <div>
                                                <input type="hidden" name="-db" value="<?php echo $databaseName ?>"> <input type="hidden" name="-lay" value=
                                                "<?php echo $layoutName ?>"> <input type="hidden" name="-action" value="new">
                                            </div>
                                            <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="6" class="record">
                                                <!-- Display record field values -->
                                                <tr class="field">
                                                    <td class="field_name">
                                                        Name
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td class="field_data">
                                                        <?php $fieldValue =          $record->getField('Name', 0) ; ?><input class="fieldinput" type="text" size="30" name=
                                                        "<?php echo getFieldFormName('Name', 0, $record, true, 'EDITTEXT', 'text');?>" value="<?php echo $fieldValue;?>"> 
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr class="field">
                                                    <td class="field_name">
                                                        Email
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td class="field_data">
                                                        <?php $fieldValue =          $record->getField('Email', 0) ; ?><input class="fieldinput" type="text" size="30" name=
                                                        "<?php echo getFieldFormName('Email', 0, $record, true, 'EDITTEXT', 'text');?>" value="<?php echo $fieldValue;?>"> 
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr class="field">
                                                    <td class="field_name">
                                                        Record ID
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td class="field_data">
                                                        <?php $fieldValue =          $record->getField('Record ID', 0) ; ?><?php echo nl2br( $record->getField('Record ID', 0) )?>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr class="field">
                                                    <td class="field_name">
                                                        Upload
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td class="field_data">
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <!--Display record form controls-->
                                                <tr class="field">
                                                    <td class="field_name">
                                                        &nbsp;
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td class="field_data">
                                                        <input type="submit" class="buttons" name="-new" value="Save Record"> <input type="reset" class="buttons" name="Reset"
                                                        value="Reset"> <input type="button" class="buttons" onclick="window.location='home.php'" name="Cancel" value="Cancel"> 
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </form>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </td>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the confirmation page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<?php
    require_once 'fmview.php';
    require_once 'FileMaker.php';
    require_once 'error.php';

    $cgi = new CGI();
    $cgi->storeFile();

    $databaseName = ‘database’;
    $layoutName = ‘layout’;

    $userName = ‘*******’;
    $passWord = ‘*******’;

    $fm = & new FileMaker();
    $fm->setProperty('database', $databaseName);
    $fm->setProperty('username', $userName);
    $fm->setProperty('password', $passWord);

    ExitOnError($fm);
    $layout = $fm->getLayout($layoutName);
    ExitOnError($layout);

    // formats for dates and times
    $displayDateFormat = '%d/%m/%Y';
    $displayTimeFormat = '%H:%M:%S';
    $displayDateTimeFormat = '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S';
    $submitDateOrder = 'mdy';

    // create the new add command
    $newrecordrequest = $fm->newAddCommand($layoutName);
    ExitOnError($newrecordrequest);

    // get the submitted record data
    $recorddata = $cgi->get('recorddata');
    if (isset ($recorddata)) {

        //  submit the data to the db
        $result = submitRecordData($recorddata, $newrecordrequest, $cgi, $layout->listFields());

        //  clear the stored record data
        $cgi->clear('recorddata');
        ExitOnError($result);
        if ($result->getFetchCount() > 0) {
            $records = $result->getRecords();
            $record = $records[0];
        }
    }
    ExitOnError($record);
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="agentis.css">
        <title>
            Confirmation
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
                Database
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <!--Navigation Menu-->
            <?php include_once 'navigation.php' ?>
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="contentbg">
                <tr>
                    <td class="contentmidrecords">
                        <div id="contenttitlebg">
                            <h1>
                                Confirmation
                            </h1>
                        </div>
                        <table class="message" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
                        </table>
                        <div class="scrolladd">
                        <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" class="recwidth">
                                <tr>
                                    <td valign="top">
                                        <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="6" class="record">
                                            <!-- Display record field values -->
                                            <tr class="field">
                                                <td class="field_name">
                                                    Name
                                                </td>
                                                <td class="field_data">
                                                    <?php echo nl2br(storeFieldNames('Name', 0, $record, true, 'EDITTEXT', 'text'))?>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr class="field">
                                                <td class="field_name">
                                                    Email
                                                </td>
                                                <td class="field_data">
                                                    <?php echo nl2br(storeFieldNames('Email', 0, $record, true, 'EDITTEXT', 'text'))?>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr class="field">
                                                <td class="field_name">
                                                    Record ID
                                                </td>
                                                <td class="field_data">
                                                    <?php echo nl2br(storeFieldNames('Record ID', 0, $record, false, 'EDITTEXT', 'number'))?>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr class="field">
                                                <td class="field_name">
                                                Upload
                                                 </td>
                                                <td class="field_data">
     <!--  Upload image: <input name="new_image" type="file" > -->
      <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload Image Here" >
    </form>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the File upload page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Select image to upload:
        <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" class="upload_file">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
    </form>
    <?php

    // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) 
    {

        $target_dir = "uploads/";
        $target_file = $target_dir . '_'. $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"];
        $uploadOk = 1;
        $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
        if($check !== false) 
        {
            echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ". ";
            echo '<a href="'.$target_file.'">View your uploaded file here</a>';
            $uploadOk = 1;
        } 
        else 
        {
            echo "File is not an image.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }

        // Check if file already exists
        if (file_exists($target_file)) 
        {
            echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
        // Check file size
        if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) 
        {
            echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
        // Allow certain file formats
        if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"&&         $imageFileType != "gif" ) 
        {
            echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
        // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
        if ($uploadOk == 0) 
        {
            echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
        // if everything is ok, try to upload file
        } 
        else 
        {
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) 
            {
                echo " The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
            } 
            else 
            {
                echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Just to clarify, I am not having issues with renaming files on upload in general only how I would go about inputting a paramater here from a previous page, specifically the Record ID generated from Filemaker

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

At the point where you save the uploaded file, you can rename it. I have used the function move_uploaded_file (http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) to set the destination with the new file name. Since you are already passing the record ID as a parameter, you should be able to get it with $_REQUEST['Record ID'] if you add it as a hidden form input.

Comment: Hi SoliantMike, thanks for the reply. Do you know how I would structure the hidden form input? Normally I would say it was straight forward but due to the way I have used the parameter in FIlemaker I am having issues. I echo the Record ID on the previous page using: <?php echo nl2br(storeFieldNames('Record ID', 0, $record, false, 'EDITTEXT', 'number'))?>. I was thinking something more like: <input type="hidden" name="recordid" value="<?php echo $_POST['Record ID']; ?>">. But I have had no such luck in getting this working.

Comment: That looks close, but the name parameter looks wrong. Should it be name="Record ID" instead?

Comment: Unfortunately still nothing, even with the correct paramater name. I think that it may be a problem with the way the paramter is passed on the previous page as it is part of the $record variable, I still dont know how I would reference that and pull out specifically the 'Record ID'

Comment: You can always view the source code before submitting to see if that variable is being populated.

Answer (score 0):

Actually i don't know a lot about php and about file maker but once i had done uploading pictures and save them after renaming like this

```
$params = $this->input->post();
    $path_to_upload_folder = BASEPATH . '../assets/user_docs/';
    $licence_path = $path_to_upload_folder . 'licence_' . $current_time . '.jpg';
    base64_to_jpeg($params['licence'], $licence_path);
```

hope this will help you...

Comment: Thanks for the input, I have managed to rename the file already using specific input or a date etc. It's just inputting the RecordID from Filemaker that is really causing me issues

Comment: sorry i can't help you with filemaker issue.. i have no idea about it